# Can I SQL join a table twice?

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, subquery

I have two entities: Proposal and Vote.

- Proposal: A user can make a proposition.
- Vote: A user can vote for a proposition.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `proposal` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);

CREATE TABLE `vote` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idea_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

Now I want to fetch rising Propsals, which means:

- Proposal title
- Total number of all time votes
- has received votes within the last 3 days

I am trying to fetch without a sub`SELECT` because I am using doctrine which doesn't allow sub`SELECT`s. So my approach is to fetch by joining the `vote`s table twice (first for fetching the total amount of votes, second to be able to create a `WHERE` clause to filter last 3 days) and do a `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT
  p.title,
  COUNT(v.p_id) AS votes,
  DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(x.updated))
FROM proposal p
JOIN vote v ON p.id = v.p_id
INNER JOIN vote x ON p.id = x.p_id
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(x.updated)) < 3
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY votes DESC;
```

It's clear that this will return a wrong `votes` amount as it triples the votes' `COUNT()`. It's actually [image: 2^n], because it creates a cartesian product just as a [`CROSS JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) does.

Is there any way I can get the proper amount without using a sub`SELECT`?

Comment: Why not just execute two queries and "join" them afterwards? :-)

Comment: @Smutje - Why not persist all data in csv or text files and join them in memory?

Comment: Because SQL provides a nice way to query data - but I have a strong aversion against thinking too much about how to store business logic in DBMS technology without just a feasible and understandable solution.

Comment: @Smutje - fair enough.  I have an aversion to un-necessarily scanning data stored in an RDBMS twice, doubling network traffic and thus also increasing latency, and re-inventing available server side technology (joins) on the client side.  Perhaps that's a micro-optimisation.  But I certainly can't see `COUNT(CASE WHEN)` as being particularly difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, you can create a kind of `COUNTIF` function using this pattern:
- `COUNT(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <field> ELSE NULL END)`

For example...

```
SELECT
  p.title,
  COUNT(v.p_id) AS votes,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN v.updated >= DATEADD(DAY, -3, CURRENT_DATE()) THEN v.p_id ELSE NULL END) AS new_votes
FROM
  proposal p
JOIN
  vote     v
    ON p.id = v.p_id
GROUP BY
   p.title
ORDER BY
   COUNT(v.p_id) DESC
;
```

Comment: Yeah, very nice approach. Thanks!